# How do I get the cookies of the active session to give it to the post request with python?

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests, header, http-post

I have a question about cookies from a website.
If I do a request manually on the Website, it hands over the header with cookies.
cookie is for example this:

cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IjBCMnNTdFNmV3lCawererwadsf0SXc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiTWtZUDduSkFXdzRobERtQ0YxdkxreEkzYzJtWFwvUEVyMHgyT2ljN2EyeXg3XasdfweUUwQzhGRWowVEp5VygsdgfewTQ2MGJmNjEzZmYyNmU4YjdhYTQyMzkyNTYzYjFjMTQ4MDQ5NjlkNDQ0ZGQ4NGRiZDE5YjNhYTRhMzA5ODMifQ%3D%3D

but how can I get that cookie with my request? I want to send a post request, with the data in it, but I dont know how to send this cookie with the request Header or how to generate it?I dont want to put it in manually it should get it from the website. or does it automatically send this cookie with the header?

Thank you!
Elias

I dont get the thing with the laravel_session cookie- where can i get it from?

Comment: You can use a `request.Session` to automatically keep track of cookies. Any requests you make with that session will send the cookies along.

Comment: but how can I see that cookies? and what is that laravel session? i simply dont get it, because if i send a request to the website i only get the __cfduid=d746938d09wwefasgf9fac4d68adf835 cookie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you with your question because this how send cookies with a python request. Even if this is from wikipedia it is an example to send cookies with a request.

```
import requests

cookies = {'enwiki_session': '17ab96bd8ffbe8ca58a78657a918558'}

r = requests.post('http://wikipedia.org', cookies=cookies)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to get a cookie from the current session, then send it along with a request. This should do that.

```
import requests

req_url = 'http://foo.bar.com'
req_data = {'some': 'data'}

session = requests.Session()
response = requests.get(req_url)
cookie_to_send = session.cookies.getdict()['cookie_name']

requests.post(url=req_url, data=req_data, cookie={'cookie_name': cookie_to_send})
```